# How to use individual JS files in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap, but would like to reduce the size of the Javascript.
I only need dropdown/collapse and sometimes carousel, so I want to include only those.

There is a folder "dist" with every single script individually.
I tried including them via -SCRIPT- tag. It does not work at all and produces lots of errors in the console.

Do I need specific other script files too, or is the JS in the dist-folder just not suitable for that?

Please forgive me, I have very little knowledge about JS and english is not my first language.

Simply put, how do I include only the needed JS into Bootstrap5?
I am on Windows and **do NOT have NPM or any other bundler/packager/installer**.

I am surprised, there is no dedicated website for configuring the JS.
I googled a lot but did not find anything related to my question.

Comment: Check out this resource for customizing Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/overview/

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/optimize/#lean-javascript

Comment: Thanks, but I read everything under those two links already.
They seem to all use package managers which I DO NOT HAVE

I need a solution for editor/browser only, without any external tools.
OR readily comiled and working single JS files.

Answer (score 4):

**First call basic utilities then call individual components [bootstrap 5.2.3]**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

My first observation is that you may be heading down the premature optimisation path. The difference between the minimal bootstrap build, and the individual components isn't huge. And on top of this, the main advantage of using a CDN is that the browser will likely have already loaded and cached it (from use in another site: it's a common resource) so trying to do anything non-standard will increase load-times, not reduce them.

But if you're set on using the individual components, they are available on the CDN too, as described on the [bootstrap site](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/contents/).

Make sure to use the `integrity` and `crossorigin` attributes to protect your site from leaking information to the CDN, and also being attacked via the CDN. If you're new to this, have a read of this page on [subresource integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity).

Comment: Thank you, that link was interesting.
However, it only describes the precompiled files.

Question: are the .js files in the js/dist folder "real" and ready Javascript already or do they need to be compiled or something before usage?

If so, I would not know how to do that.

My ideal scenario would be to identify all single js-files needed, then merge them into a single file and include this in my project.
It should be considerably smaller than the provided .min.js as well.

Comment: You can include them individually, details here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/javascript/

Comment: which brings me back to my original question, if i can include them individually (I am talking about the SCRIPT tag inside HTML), why don't they work?

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser console?

Answer (score -2):

**Use Bootstrap Cdn**

You can simply use this link

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Now u dont need to include from folder

Comment: Can you please read before posting?
I do NOT .... N O T want the full pack but INDIVIDUAL parts.

Comment: Also, you should never use a versioned CDN without including the integrity hashes, as if something goes wrong and the CDN is comproimised, you'll then be loading dangerous code straight into your app. The recommended approach, along with integrity hashes, is available on the bootstrap site: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/